# Changing output of Assetic doesn't make it read from the same folder

Tags: php, symfony, assetic

I'm having a small problem with Assetic in Symfony. It generates the files in the static folder, but it tries to take them out from the web folder, it doesn't go one level deeper to the static folder. I've obviously deleted the cache.

This is my config file

```
assetic:
    debug:          "%kernel.debug%"
    use_controller: "%kernel.debug%"
    write_to:       %kernel.root_dir%/../web/static/
    filters:
        uglifyjs2:
            bin:  %kernel.root_dir%/Resources/node_modules/uglify-js/bin/uglifyjs
        uglifycss:
            bin:  %kernel.root_dir%/Resources/node_modules/uglifycss/uglifycss
        cssrewrite: ~
```

This is how a file would look like:

```
{% javascripts
    'assets/vendor/scrollreveal/dist/scrollReveal.min.js'
    'assets/vendor/seiyria-bootstrap-slider/dist/bootstrap-slider.min.js'
    'js/select2.min.js'
    'js/smoothscroll.js'
    'js/languages.js'
    'js/infinity-run-lsww.js' filter='uglifyjs2' %}
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset_url }}"></script>
{% endjavascripts %}
```

Am I missing something?

If it helps, I'm also getting an out of memory error when warming up the cache.

```
Fatal error: Out of memory (allocated 1965293568) (tried to allocate 65488 bytes) in E:\svn\medapp\vendor\twig\twig\lib\Twig\Environment.php on line 378
```

I wasn't getting this before adding the `write_to` parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to do it with a feature recently added in Symfony 2.7

This needs to be added to config.yml

```
framework:
    assets:
        packages:
            assetic:
                base_path: /static
```

And then add `package='assetic'` to the assetic template.

```
{% stylesheets 'css/themes/blackTheme.css' package='assetic' filter='cssrewrite' filter='?uglifycss' %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset_url }}" />
{% endstylesheets %}
```

Clear and warm cache, run assetic:dump and all works.

The problem are fonts and images in css. They follow the old relative path to `web/` and not `web/static`, so that's a problem I'm facing currently. I believe [FkrCssURLRewriteBundle](https://github.com/fkrauthan/FkrCssURLRewriteBundle) could be of help to fix that problem.